# What does a parameter without equal in a django models.Field means?

Tags: python, django, django-models, parameters

I was reviewing a django repo in git hub and find this way of fields declaration

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class Usuario(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

     usuario = models.CharField(_('Usuario'), max_length=60, unique=True)
     is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff status'), default=False)
```

I don't understand for what is the _('Usuario') and _('staff status') parameters.

Could someone explain me this? Thanks

Comment: It is `verbose_name` parameter: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#verbose-field-names

Comment: Thanks petr, you helped me a lot